# Can I reduce flyback transformer into a single inductance to calculate the duty cycle of the MOSFET?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, duty-cycle

I am trying to calculate the duty cycle of the MOSFET in a flyback topology SMPS. From the selected converter's datasheet, I am given the equation:

[image: Duty Cycle Equation]

Since I am using a flyback topology, what is my L in this instance? Do I need to reduce the transformer to some equivalent inductance or is it just the primary side inductance because the MOSFET is connected on the primary side?

**Note**: The datasheet describes L as "*L is the inductor value in H*"

Comment: Where did your formula for D come from? Shouldn't it equal the square root of the RH side of the equation shown?

Comment: It came from the manufacturer's datasheet for the flyback controller. It does not have a square root in the datasheet. This is for the DCM duty cycle if that changes anything.

Comment: Please link the data sheet. I need to check it.

Answer (score 0):

\$L\$ for that equation is the primary side inductance in Henrys.

Comment: Why do I not need to include the secondary or leakage inductances in that value?

Answer (score 0):

Flyback transformers are probably the easiest to understand of all of the topologies.  We'll ignore winding resistance for now and talk about discontinuous mode which is easiest to understand.

- When the MOSFET is turned on, the secondary winding is not active, and the input voltage causes the current in the primary to increase.  Since V = L(di/dt) you can readily calculate the rate this current increases and determine the current for a given pulsewidth.
- The energy stored in the inductor (in joules) is 1/2(Li^2) at the point at which the MOSFET is turned off.
- At this point, the primary is no longer active, and the energy is discharged through current in the secondary windings.  Each pulse therefore represents a packet of energy that is transferred from the primary to the secondary.  You can increase the amount of energy by increasing the primary "on" time or by increasing the frequency of a fixed pulsewidth.  The power transferred is the number of joules per second, so the duty cycle can be inferred from the power and frequency.

So you are absolutely correct, and you make the excellent point that the mutual inductance value will have a direct effect on the transformer output.  The same is true for the effects of winding resistance,  hysteresis, saturation and core losses.  You can readily see that all of these are ignored in your equation, which therefore must assume ideal, mutual inductors (no leakage inductance).  Any transformer equation is an approximation, and as a designer you must decide how many parameters you want to use in your calculations.  Each term you add brings added complexity, but gives a closer approximation to the true performance.  But often the simplest approximation is used, followed by some experiments with prototypes.

Good luck!